# Strange blue subtitle when plotting objects from the RandomFields package

Tags: r, plot

The`plot` method for `RFspatialGridDataFrame` outputs a weird blue "subtitle" when passing `main` or axis label arguments to the `plot` function.

```
install.packages("RandomFields")
library(RandomFields)

model <- RPbernoulli(RMexp(scale = 3), threshold = 1)
set.seed(100)
simulation <- RFsimulate(model, x = 1:138, y = 1:74)
plot(simulation, main = "This is an example title")
```

The following is a screeshot of the output

[image]

Strangely enough, this appears to be a feature, as running other example for the RandomFields documentation shows.

Is there any way of not outputting this blue repeated title? I have tried fiddling with other graphical arguments (such as setting `legend = F`) but the behavior does not change.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to be raised with `RandomFields` authors. Find their Git page for ticket issue or email author(s) (see [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RandomFields/index.html) page) with reproducible example.

Comment: @Parfait added an answer if you're interested in some follow-up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contacted the maintainers of the `RandomFields` package, and it appears to be a setting in `RFoptions`.

By setting `RFoptions(grPrintlevel = 0)` before the plots, this behavior can be avoided. More information can be found under [`?RFoptions`](http://127.0.0.1:26182/library/RandomFields/html/RFoptions.html) in section 10 regarding graphics. The relevant part regarding `grPrintlevel` reads

> ```
> grPrintlevel: integer values 0, 1, 2; only relevant when simulations are 
> plotted. The higher the more text is shown in the plot.
> Default: 1.
> ```

Comment: Consider linking and even quoting the `grPrintlevel` argument in `RFoptions` from [CRAN docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RandomFields/RandomFields.pdf) for future readers. Quoting needed in case CRAN doc link breaks.